# jQuery UI Tabs - How to Select a Tab on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

Using the [`jQuery UI Tabs`](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) component, is it possible to select new tabs on hover instead of when clicking on them?

I found an example [here](http://stilbuero.de/jquery/tabs/mouseover.html), but this does not seem to work with the latest (stable) versions of jQuery and jQuery UI tabs.

Finally, one of the [developers mentions that this will be an option in Tabs 3](http://markmail.org/message/yymcisfniiyrf6ls#query:jquery%20tabs%20rollover+page:1+mid:w3kazcwusiyxahsz+state:results), which has since been released, but I cannot find any mention of it in the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[demo here](http://ui.jquery.com/demos/tabs#mouseover) Its running with 1.6rc4 which I consider as stable as any other of the ui releases!